# Running time driven backup script but just once

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an archiving script which is now working as it should (I have included it below).  However I would like it to run only at 1 am on the date the sheet is in use for.I make the sheets and name them months in advance and they sit in drive until the day of use (maybe earlier if we get pre bookings) but i don't want them to run the script and archive every night at 2 AM!  Is there any way to make the time driven trigger only once?  At moment the time driven trigger doesn't copy over when i copy the blank sheet either.  Any ideas or a better way of automating this?  Thanks.

```
  function dataBackup() {
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = 
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {

    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

    var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // Changed to stop 
  inadvertent cell changes, also made text white so not seen.
    var data = 
 inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return 
 row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
    }
    var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 
 1).getValue();
    var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return 
 Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
    var date = new Date(date); 
    var getDate = new Date(getDate);
    if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != 
date.getMonth()) {     

        if (data.length != 0) {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 
data.length);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 
data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
        } else {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 
 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your trigger to only go off once monthly? E.g. Weekly or set date?

As for triggers copying over they won't due to the way Google have made their service. Doesn't take long to set them up.

Comment: It does take a while to set them up when I copy the blank sheet 365 times! Due to it sometimes being 3 months (not 12 months) a monthly trigger wouldn't work as it would still generate data up to 3 times before the actual day / date it is for. Any thoughts on a way to get this working or where I should look?

Comment: @Paul let me have a look when I get home. This would actually help me at work so I'll try make a script. I could make a script for you to run every 3 months by just simply loading it up or sending a command to slack etc

Comment: OK, thanks if you can annotate as well so i can modify if needed, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Paul I always annotate my work :) I like to publish it

Comment: On a related note I have included a menu button in the above script now so it can be manually activated and that is working OK.  But not sure about the time trigger so I made some copies but found I need to authorize each script to run it.  Do you know how to automate that?  Or should i be trying a completely different approach to automatically backing up our daily sheet.

Comment: To be honest you could just write some app script to copy it and paste it in a folder. You'd just have to run it or set a trigger for every 3 months etc